# Burnside's Lemma and Geometry

Tags: gr.group-theory, tag-removed, geometry, finite-groups, co.combinatorics

I think one of the most interesting results in Elementary Group Theory is the so-called "[Burnside's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)", counting the numbers of orbits of a (finite) group action.

I wonder if there is any (interesting) application in Elementary Geometry (I mean Euclidean, hyperbolic or elliptic geometry).

Searching on Google, I've found the article "[Applying Burnside’s lemma to a one-dimensional
Escher problem](http://users.wpi.edu/~bservat/strippat.pdf)" by T. Pisanski, but it sounds to me rather a combinatorial result.

Comment: There may be something in the book by Paul B Yale, Geometry and Symmetry, published in 1968 (2nd edition, Dover, 1988). Well, it has the word "Geometry" in the title, and Burnside's Lemma is discussed in the 1st chapter. 

Comment: "Burnside's Lemma" is not due to Burnside according to a 1979 paper of P. Neumann called (appropriately) "A lemma that is not Burnside's". Neumann attributes the result to Cauchy and Frobenius.

Comment: @Marty Thank you for your comment, that's why I wrote "so-called"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Burnside Lemma can be used as a first step to classify all finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$: it gives you that there are at most $3$ orbits in the action of any finite group $G$ on the set of intersections between axes of elements of $G$ and the unit sphere.

Comment: Which, of course, can then be used to classify the Platonic solids.